# Consulting for a competitor under a different role: possible conflict of interest?

Tags: united-states, freelancing, conflict

I work as a circuit design engineer at my full-time (W2) company where I got recently promoted from circuit test engineer.

My previous role of circuit test engineer at this company involved circuit analysis and reporting on safety status of all the work in progress.

An upcoming competitor is interested in hiring me as a consultant to help them out with their testing. I was also offered but refused to take on the responsibility of design as I have inside information from my current employer and I would also have inside information about the competitor.

Both companies have a common pool of investors and advisers but the management are separate.

In the circuit design business, having information about competitors designs in progress can be the difference between staying ahead or not, and that's why I left that part out of the particular offered consulting role.

How can I take on this new consultant role in a way that avoids or mitigates the conflict of interest with both companies?

Comment: this question could probably be saved by asking what the best is a way to take on the second role with out creating a conflict of interest. the 2 3 and 4 questions should be redacted completely as they will always be off topic here either as opinion or legal questions.  Ill give you some time to respond to my edit.  If this is acceptable to you ill seek to have the question reopened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I would run away from this as fast as I possibly could. The potential to get two employers in your professional specialty angry with you or the potential to end up in court if anything goes wrong is just too high.

That fact that two roles are different is irrelevant, you have knowledge your current employer would, no doubt, not want their competition to know. The company you consult for may pressure you to give information, the current employer would be angry if you didn't tell them and they found it (it is a small world out there, it is highly likely they will find out) and they are likely to tell you not to do it if you tell them about the opportunity or worse, expect you to tell them what you found out at the other company. If confidential information is found through other means, you may get the blame because you were working at both places. This is a no-win situation.

If you want extra money, find moonlighting work outside the direct competitors of your employer.